# windows command line call does not run in R

Tags: r

I am checking to see if MikTex packages are locally installed via command line mpm call.

when i run a system call in R I get this

```
> system("mpm --list-package-names | grep 12many")
mpm: This utility does not accept non-option arguments.
Warning message:
running command 'mpm --list-package-names | grep 12many' had status 1
```

but it does run correctly in the CMD

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>mpm --list-package-names | grep 12many
12many
```

what is the difference between the two settings that could cause it not to work in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `?system`

> command must be an executable (extensions ‘.exe’, ‘.com’) or a batch file (extensions ‘.cmd’ and ‘.bat’): these extensions are tried in turn if none is supplied.) This means that redirection, pipes, DOS internal commands, ... cannot be used: see shell if you want to pass a shell command-line.

```
shell("mpm --list-package-names | grep 12many")
```